# Retrieve Repository URL field Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

is there a way to call via code the GUI field "Repository URL" in order to use its value on my Jenkins pipeline?

[image: Jenkins GUI]

Answer (score 1):

The url of your git repository is part of the `scm` object. You can get the url by calling `scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()`.
The method `getUserRemoteConfigs()` will return a list with instances of type `UserRemoteConfig`. This class has a method called getUrl() which will return the configured url as a string.

Further information: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.html

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GIT_URL** environment variable of jenkins.
i.e. echo "Git URL is ${GIT_URL}"
This will give you the git url used in the current jenkins job.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you too. Another perfect answer that fit perfectly with my problem.