# Using Declarative Jenkins pipeline from SCM - Subversion - How to get svn Url?

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This looks like very basic question about Jenkins usage.

I have `Jenkinsfile` located in root folder of my Subversion repository tree. There are many branches (versions/tags) of the product - everywhere is the same `Jenkinsfile`. So far very basic setup, I suppose.

I need to provide some steps with **current Subversion repository branch/url**.
There are some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705750/retrieve-repository-url-field-jenkins) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937337/jenkins-pipeline-get-repository-url-variable-under-pipeline-script-from-scm), but none is working solution for Subversion.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
    stage("test") {
      steps {
        echo "Start pipeline "
        // commented-out = not working
        //echo scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()
        //echo scm
        script {
            println "Current svn url/branch: "//??? + scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like this

```
pipeline {
  agent any;
  stages  {
    stage('test'){
      steps {
        script {
          def s = checkout scm;
          if      (s.GIT_URL != null) {
            print s.GIT_URL
            print s.GIT_BRANCH
            print s.GIT_COMMIT
          }
          else if (s.SVN_URL != null) {
            print s.SVN_REVISION
            print s.SVN_REVISION_1
            print s.SVN_URL
            print s.SVN_URL_1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note- This works fine with GIT and SVN, but a bit differently.

Comment: Yes, this works. Of course scm object has different properties for svn. Thanks!